# How to tell a MS word paragraph from a display-mode equation

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to use VBA to do something about a normal MS word paragraph. But a display mode equation looks just like a paragraph. Can anybody tell me, please, the difference between them? Or provide a VBA example to distinguish them.

[image]

```
Function IsADisplayModeEquation(ParagraphIndex As Long)
    Dim ParagrapLineNum As Long
    Dim EquationLineNum As Long
    ParagrapLineNum = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(ParagraphIndex).Range.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber)

    n = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\page").Range.OMaths.Count
    For I = 1 To n
        EquationLineNum = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\page").Range.OMaths(I).Range.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber)
        If (ParagrapLineNum = EquationLineNum) And ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\page").Range.OMaths(I).Type = wdOMathDisplay Then
            IsADisplayModeEquation = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next I
    IsADisplayModeEquation = False
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

A ugly function：

```
Function IsADisplayModeEquation(ParagraphIndex As Long)
    Dim ParagrapLineNum As Long
    Dim EquationLineNum As Long
    ParagrapLineNum = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(ParagraphIndex).Range.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber)

    n = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\page").Range.OMaths.Count
    For I = 1 To n
        EquationLineNum = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\page").Range.OMaths(I).Range.Information(wdFirstCharacterLineNumber)
        If (ParagrapLineNum = EquationLineNum) And ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\page").Range.OMaths(I).Type = wdOMathDisplay Then
            IsADisplayModeEquation = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next I
    IsADisplayModeEquation = False
End Function
```